# webhdfs create file exception

Tags: hadoop, webhdfs

I am using hadoop 2.7.1 on centos 7

If I want to use webhdfs with Hadoop cluster

I should configure this property

```
<property>
      <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
      <value>true</value>
</property>
```

but what else?

my name node ip is 192.168.4.128

when I use Firefox on Windows 8 and send this  get request

```
http://192.168.4.128:50070/webhdfs/v1/hadoopDir/A.txt/?user.name=SYSTEM&op=OPEN
```

I can open a file and see it's content

but when I send `PUT` request

```
http://192.168.4.128:50070/webhdfs/v1/HadoopDir/B.txt/?user.name=SYSTEM&op=CREATE&data=true
```

I get the following response

```
{"RemoteException":{"exception":"IllegalArgumentException","javaClassName":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","message":"Invalid value for webhdfs parameter \"op\": No enum constant org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.resources.GetOpParam.Op.CREATE"}}
```

why in `GET` operation which is opening the file everything is ok, but not in `PUT`.

Any other configurations should be handled to process this request?

Comment: How do you send a PUT request? Browsers don't send PUT requests from the address bar

Comment: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Hadoop-101-Training-Quickstart/WebHDFS-error-with-HTTP-PUT-operations-in-Cloudera-Quickstart-VM/m-p/39648#M2399

Comment: thanks very much for your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebHDFS performs four kinds of HTTP operations (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) whereas Web Browsers normally do support only GET and POST.

Include some plugins like [RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/) (for Firefox), [Advanced REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) (for Chrome) for sending HTTP PUT and HTTP DELETE requests.

Alternatively, you can use `curl` from command line.

**Note:** WebHDFS is enabled by default. So, the property added in `hdfs-site.xml` is redundant (just saying).